# RFID Error on Java

Tags: java, windows-mobile

I'm having this issue with a java app run on RFID scanner. I have added the classes. But it seems the method in the class could not be located. Anyone know of something perhaps?

```
    Exception in thread "xShadow-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ReadEventCallback
    at symbol.RFIDBase.RFID_EnableReadTagInventoryCallback()
    at symbol.RFIDReader$RFIDActions.readTag()
    at symbol.RFIDReader$RFIDActions.readTag()
    at com.vmt.plugins.symbol.barcodescanner.services.ScannerImplementation$RfidTriggerListener.actio    nPerformed()
    at symbol.RFIDReader$RFIDActions.TriggerCallback()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Exception in thread "xShadow-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ReadEventCallback
```

It seems you have wrong version of jars in classpath. I would suggest make sure the code you have is compatible with the jar version you have in classpath.